# Enable "disabled Multiselect" using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

here's my code below. On page load, all multiselect are disabled but once the user click the enable button, all multiselect should be enable. Here's my code below. I'm not able to make this work, I wonder why. But if I add "`$('#multidiv option').prop('disabled', false);`" on first load, it works, but all my multiselect will be enabled on first load. I want to disabled all on first load but enable all by clicking a button. Thanks.

```
<div id="multidiv">    
<label style="float:left; margin-right:-2px;">Target Android Device</label>                                 
    <div class="span5" style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
        <select id="android" disabled="disabled" multiple="multiple" name="android[]">
            <option value="Nexus">Nexus</option>
            <option value="HTC">HTC One</option>
            <option value="Sony">Sony Xperia</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code below:

```
$('#enable_button').on("click",function(){
    $('#multidiv option').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#android').multiSelect(); //using "http://loudev.com/" plugin
```

Comment: Try `$('#multidiv option').removeAttr('disabled');`. Where is `multidiv` element in your html ?

Comment: I've tried that, it's not working. I've no idea why. Maybe is it because of the plugin?

Comment: Added multidiv element, I forgot to add in here... Please check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. 
This `$('#multidiv option').removeAttr('disabled');` code actually works. It's the plugin problem.

By adding `$('#android').multiSelect('refresh');` it works fine now. The plugin needs to be refreshed after this code `$('#multidiv option').removeAttr('disabled');`

Thanks for all for trying to help btw.

Comment: you saved my countless hours looking into the same issue. I am using [http://loudev.com] multiselect and had the same issue.

Comment: Glad that it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `id` of the `<select>` itself:

```
$('#enable_button').on("click",function(){
    $('#android option').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Because actually I have a few more multiselects under that div.

Comment: can you post a fiddle with this plugin added?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script;

```
$('#android').multiselect('disable');
and
$("#android").multiselect('enable');
```

its work for agungpanduan.com